# What correlation method should I use to analyze financial timeseries?

Tags: correlation

I need to check if two price lists move togheter. I three methods:

1. Pearson
2. Spearman
3. Kendall

Could someone explain me why I should use a method instead of other to check if those price lists move in the same direction? I know that Pearson is often used for this kind of analysis... Is that correct?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pearson correlation is used if you suspect you have a linear relation in your data (if you think you can do simple linear regression on your data, you can also use pearson correlation). If you only assume *any* relation between two variables, you should use either kendall or spearman correlation.  I personally prefer spearman correlation, since I have a firmer grasp of it. It is essentially pearson correlation on the ranks of observations instead of the numerical values.

A useful tool to see if pearson correlation is appropriate, at least if you only have a few variables (say 10 or less): Plot them all pairwise, which most statistics software should have a function to do, and inspect if some obvious linear pattern is present.

The level of your data (ratio, ordinal, nominal etc.) should not guide your choice of correlation measure other than to clue you in that you probably don't have a linear relation.

Comment: Could you give some reference of that which you said in last sentence?

Comment: @user152509 Among other places, John Tukey has a scathing criticism in "Data Analysis and Behavioral Science" (Collected Works, volume III, pp 243-245).  "If [limiting statistical methods based on scale type were] generally adopted it would not only lead to inefficient analysis of data, but it would also lead to failure to give any answer at all to questions whose answers are perfectly good, though slightly approximate."

Comment: @whuber: It means one can use Pearson correlation if they found linear relationship between variables?

Comment: It's hard to see what a linear relationship between nominal variables would mean, but this is a good point about ratio, interval and ordinal data.  Stevens typology is useful, but it's a guideline, not a box. 
I wrote about this on my blog: http://www.statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/nominal-ordinal-interval-ratio-stevens-typology-and-some-problems-with-it/

Answer (score 2):

The Pearson correlation is for interval/ ratio data and it is quite suitable for your problem.

The Kendall correlation is used for non-parametric data ( If assumption do not full fill in your data)

The Spearman correlation is for ordinal data and I am sure this not a case with your data.

Comment: what do you mean with "If assumption do not full fill in your data" ?

Comment: It means the assumptions of Pearson correlation. There are five assumptions that are made with respect to Pearson's correlation:

1. The variables must be either interval or ratio measurements 
2. The variables must be approximately normally distributed.    
3. There is a linear relationship between the two variables.
4. Outliers are either kept to a minimum or are removed entirely.     
5. There is homoscedasticity of the data. 

If any of these assumption violate then I would recommend Kendall correlation.